# Accessing protected static method from anonymous function in php?

Tags: php, static-methods

I have a following problem: in a static method of some class A I define anonymous function within from I want to call another protected static method of the class A. The problem is I need to make it work in php 5.3. Any ideas? Here is a sample code:

```
class A {
    public static function test() 
    {
        $class = new static;
        $f = function () use ($class) {
            // problem: I need to call static::foo() from here
            return $class::foo();
        };

        print $f();
    }
    protected static function foo() { return 1; }
}

class B extends A {
    protected static function foo() { return 2; }
}

// assuming this will output 2
B::test();
```

This works in php >= 5.4, but in php 5.3 I get `Fatal error: Call to protected method B::foo() from context '' ...`.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'd question why you want to do this in the first place, but ... just upgrade. PHP 5.3 reached EOL 2 years ago.

Comment: Well its not a code that runs on my server, I am working on a project that needs to work on 5.3, so that is not an option for me. And why I need to do that - imagine that function $f in my example is a callback that receives data that I want to examine via the `foo()` method (for example callback passed to usort).

Comment: Your callback doesn't have to be an anonymous function ... it can easily be another class method.

Comment: Yes, that would work and it is an acceptable solution for my case, thanks!